# golang function type inheritance?

Tags: go

Consider this example in Go language:

```
type I interface {
    get() string
}

type S struct {}
func (s *S) get() string {
    return "here!"
}
var sSupplier = func() *S {
    return &S{}
}

func foo(supplier func () I) {
    i := supplier()
    println(i)
}

func main() {
    foo(sSupplier) // compile error, type mismatch
}
```

Type `S` inherit interface `I`. But apparently type `func () *S` does not inherit `func () I`, so I cannot call `foo` with `sSupplier` in place of the `supplier` function. Is there a way to fix it without forcing `sSupplier` to return type `I`?

In java you can use generics to do something like `<T extends I> void foo(Supplier<T> supplier) {...}` then call `foo(sSupplier);` with `Supplier<S> sSupplier` type. I'm not sure if similar approach is possible in go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think for a bit about what generics do for you, they are really a way to ask the compiler to compile, on the spot, an anonymous wrapper function or lambda or whatever is needed to map from some concrete type.  That is, given something like (I'll use C++ syntax here rather than Java as I'm much more familiar with C++):

```
template<T>
void f(T obj) {
    // do stuff with the object
}
```

you're telling the compiler that when it sees `f(int_value)` it should build a function `f` that takes an `int`, and when it sees `f(struct S)` it should build a function `f` that takes a `struct S`, and so on.  (This is a bit more natural in Java than it is in C++'s C underpinnings since Java does the whole argument-matching thing to decide which of these various `f` functions to call.)

In effect, instead of writing the actual function, you write a *template*—hence the C++ keyword—that the compiler can use to, at compile time, *produce* the function you really wanted.  Since Go lacks generics, it lacks this sort of template-expansion trick.

That leaves you with several obvious alternatives, though.  One is exemplified by `go:generate` (see, e.g., [Explain go generate in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37362054/1256452)).  In this particularly simple case, though, you can just write the expansion yourself in line:

```
foo(func() I { return sSupplier() })
```

See a more complete example on the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aLOB1QB-Xkf).  I replacd your `println(i)` with `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", i)` to print the interface object's value in a slightly more useful form.